# How does one deal with missing values from a continuous variable in random forest models

Tags: random-forest, missing-data

I have been attempting to run a random forest model, the model seems to go through ok but once I try to use predict on the test dataset I run into errors. One of the variables has missing values, this variable represents an 'average of previous test result'. The dataset is a collection of tests, some of them repeated tests. There are also the first tests which won't have an 'average'. At least from my own research if you had a categorical variable I could create a new category that represents this but what would I do to deal with a continuous variable?